# How to get the data from two tables which has multiple rows into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as following

Table A

```
ID ExPID ExWIPID Type  
1   15  30     P1  
2   16   0     P2
```

Table B

```
EXPID  Label     Value  
15  Label A    Label A Val  
30  Label B    Label B Val  
16  Label C    Label C Val
```

From the Above tables, Table A's PID and WIPID are both coming from Table B ID
And I want to write a query which results the following:

```
ID  PID  WIPID  Type   Label      Label     
1    15   30      P1   Label A    Label B 
2    16    0      P2   Label C    NULL
```

please help

Comment: try TableA left join TableB on TableA.PID=TableB.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a left join on wipid  for obtaion the 3 rows 2 with label and one without

```
select  a.ID, a.ExPID, a.ExWIPID, a.Type, b.Label label_x_pid, c.label label_x_wiPDi
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.exID = b.EXPID
left join tableB c on a.ExWIPID = c.EXPid
```

but if you need  only the two that match you should use inner join

```
select   a.ID, a.ExPID, a.ExWIPID, a.Type, b.Label label_x_pid, c.label label_x_wiPDi
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.exID = b.EXPID
inner join tableB c on a.ExWIPDI = c.EXPid
```

Based on your comment you should use

```
  select a.ID, a.ExPID, a.ExWIPID, a.Type, b.Label label_x_pid, c.label label_x_wiPDi 
  from tableA a 
  left join tableB b on a.exID = b.EXPID 
  left join tableB c on a.ExWIPID = c.EXPID 
  where a.ID =1
```

Comment: IT doesn't work as am not getting the values of table A

Comment: @Guest It's a `LEFT JOIN`.  How can you not get any value from it?

Comment: A left join return always  at least  the row from the main table (from tableA) ...  so check better  ..

Comment: Sorry, please check the question again I need the result something like that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it works generally but when we do the following it doesn't get the Label B on the first row:                                                                                  select  a.ID, a.PID, a.WIPID, a.Type, b.Label label_x_pid, c.label label_x_wiPDi
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.exID = b.ID
left join tableB c on a.ExWIPDI = c.id where a.ID =1

Comment: answer  updated ..  with columns name coherent with your last editing

Comment: @ scaisEdge  - Thank you. I had wrong data in the table. It works :).

Comment: I did that. Thank you again.